# Medieval Typography

Tags: html, css, typography

I am currently building a Website that uses a [blackletter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter) font. I try to make it as authentic as possible, but I want to keep the code clean. So I got a few questions

- Is it possible, to replace every semikolon (or any other letter, e.g. to autmoatically fill in the medieval sz-letter) with a dot (via css)?
- Is it bad program style to use `<br />` to correct the justification? If yes, how would you do it?
- Does anyone know an opentype blackletter-font, that is using CSS3's hist-feature?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you clarify what you mean by item 2.? What kind of justification needs correcting how? Also could you provide a link explaining what the "hist" feature is? I, for one, haven't heard of it.

Comment: This is a font issue, not a CSS issue.

Comment: What I mean with item 2 is, I want the ragged alignment to look better (I cant use justify, because the divbox is too small, it looks odd. But for the medieval look it is necessary, that the text looks like a nice block). If I use <br /> than I have hardcoded wordwraps everywhere in the text. I fear that this is no good style.

Comment: @ kinokijuf: Sry, I was not shure, where to put this, so I choosed CSS, because the CSS issues were more important for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible, to replace every semikolon (or any other letter, e.g. to autmoatically fill in the medieval sz-letter) with a dot (via css)?

the answer to that is no. You'll need JavaScript or server-side programming to do it.

Alternatively, you could of course edit the font you're using and do the substitutions there - but that's really hard. The font's license must allow it; you need to have the right tools, and you need to beprepared to deal with the possible kerning issues that simply replacing one character with another will bring.

Comment: Than I will try it the JaveScript-Way. Thank you!

Comment: I just had an idea: Would it be possible to just style a special character? E.g. to give every dot a special margin?

Comment: @Lord sure, but you'll have to wrap the character into a DOM element: `Hello` would turn into `H<span class='special_margin'>e</span>llo`

Comment: Mmmh yes, I should have known. I already did this with the initial letters. It would be a little too crazy, to da this with every uncommon character. I have to find a way to da it with JS. Thank you again. That helped.